# slow query in postgres using group by

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, optimization, indexing

I have a table named facebook_adset_insights with almost 5.5 millions rows that looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE facebook_adset_insights (
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
start_time timestamp without time zone,
impressions integer,
banner_name character varying
......);
```

banner_name might be NULL (around 100k banner_name of are NULL) and impressions might be NULL (around 80k of impressions are NULL)
banner_name is b-tree indexed and impressions is not (unnecessary).

Seems like GROUP BY and SUM is slowing the the query so I was trying to EXPLAIN ANALYZE but am not sure what is wrong with the query plan by running:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, COSTS, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, FORMAT JSON)
SELECT banner_name, sum(impressions)
FROM facebook_adset_insights
WHERE impressions IS NOT NULL AND banner_name IS NOT NULL AND start_time > '2018-02-01'
GROUP BY banner_name
```

it results:

[image]

Comment: Did you try to add an index on `banner_name`?

Comment: It is indexed.

CREATE INDEX index_facebook_adset_insights_on_banner_name ON facebook_adset_insights(banner_name text_ops);

Comment: @barbenezra what program are you using in that screenshot?

Comment: @barbenezra how did you get that screenshot?

Comment: @Aijaz I used:

1. EXPLAIN (FORMAT JSON) {YOUR SELECT QUERY} in any SQL client (Postico)
2. Took the output and pasted in https://tatiyants.com/pev/#/plans/new

Answer (score 0):

Your execution plan is perfect, and the aggregate and `GROUP BY` only takes 0.15 seconds.

The bitmap index scan is the right thing, and the `IS NOT NULL` conditions are not selective enough to be indexed.

It is expected that the bitmap heap scan that has to fetch a lot of rows from the table takes the most time.

You *might* be cheaper with an index only scan if all the columns from the `WHERE` clause and the `SELECT` list are in the index and the table is freshly vacuumed.